# How parse numbers from https arddress in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to extract two string sets from https-address. I'm using Oracle 11g and this is my data and my solution:

```
with mcte as (
select 'https://id.adsf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/9884752-6/2542595-3/Corlsdf-asdf/Corlsdf/MOB50202282' as addr from dual
union all 
select 'https://id.asdf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/2435213-2/Corlsdf-asdf/Corlsdf/KVY239229' as addr from dual
union all
select 'https://id.asdf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/6356334-0' as addr from dual
union all
select 'https://id.asdf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/6356334-0/6356324-0' as addr  from dual
union all
select 'https://id.asdf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/6356334-0/6356324-0/' as addr from dual
)
select  addr, 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr,  '(Organizations\/)(\d+)', 1, 1, null, 2) AS num1,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr,  '(Organizations\/)(\d+)', 1, 1, null, 3) AS num2
from mcte
;
```

This does not result the correct set which should be like this for NUM1 and NUM2

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
|                                                    id                                                    |   num1    |   num2    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| https://id.adsf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/9884752-6/2542595-3/Corlsdf-asdf/Corlsdf/MOB50202282 | 9884752-6 | 2542595-3 |
| https://id.asdf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/2435213-2/Corlsdf-asdf/Corlsdf/KVY239229             | 2435213-2 | NULL      |
| https://id.asdf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/6356334-0                                            | 6356334-0 | NULL      |
| https://id.asdf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/6356334-0/6356324-0                                  | 6356334-0 | 6356324-0 |
| https://id.asdf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/6356334-0/6356324-0/                                 | 6356334-0 | 6356324-0 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expressions are not correct / complete:

1. You are looking for digits only (`\d`), rather than looking for the minus sign also (`[0-9-]`).
2. They lack the second number you are looking for.

It should be this instead:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr, '(Organizations\/)([0-9-]+)', 1, 1, null, 2) AS num1,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr, '(Organizations\/)([0-9-]+)\/([0-9-]+)', 1, 1, null, 3) AS num2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr,  '(Organizations\/)([^\/]+)', 1, 1, null, 2) AS num1,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr,  '(Organizations\/)([^\/]+\/)([0-9\-]+)', 1, 1, null, 3) AS num2
```

First is: skip `Organizations/` and take everything while the symbol is not `/`.

Second is: skip `Organizations/..../` and then take continuous digits and `-`.

Here is fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/12905

Answer (score 1):

The fourth parameter to REGEXP_SUBSTR is the occurrence parameter. This should get you where you need to go:

```
with mcte as (
select 'https://id.adsf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/9884752-6/2542595-3/Corlsdf-asdf/Corlsdf/MOB50202282' as addr from dual
union all 
select 'https://id.asdf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/2435213-2/Corlsdf-asdf/Corlsdf/KVY239229' as addr from dual
union all
select 'https://id.asdf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/6356334-0' as addr from dual
union all
select 'https://id.asdf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/6356334-0/6356324-0' as addr  from dual
union all
select 'https://id.asdf.fi/dfad2/services/org/Organizations/6356334-0/6356324-0/' as addr from dual
)
select  REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr, '/([[:digit:]\-])+', 1, 1) AS p1,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr, '/([[:digit:]\-])+', 1, 2) AS p2
from mcte;
```

Results:

```
p1          p2
/9884752-6  /2542595-3
/2435213-2  
/6356334-0  
/6356334-0  /6356324-0
/6356334-0  /6356324-0
```